# Which command is used to convert wsdl to objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, terminal, wsdl, command

Previously I have created studs in Objective-C for WSDL webservice using terminal.

Now I forgot that command for generating Objective-C class for wsdl services.

Currently I am using **MOS Sierra** the **Wsdl2Obj** is not working.
I have download from here [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsdl2objc/downloads')

**Which gives an error**

> You can’t use this version of the application “WSDL2ObjC” with this version of macOS.

I remember there is a command for generating wsdl to obj stubs classes.